# iOS Simulator : Black screen with navigation bar

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have changed a bunch of UIViewControllers, added buttons and the like, and not my app won't start, not sure what I did wrong.

I get a black screen, **BUT**, I see the statusbar and a navigation bar.

I searched for keywords xcode/ios simulator/swift/objective-c along with black screen, but all suggestions (e.g. reset content, clean, deleting all schemas, adding viewDidLoad, a couple of more) were directed towards having a *whole black screen* and thus didn't work when I tried them.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You may not have the starting view controller defined in your storyboard. Make sure there is a view controller with an arrow pointing to it on its left side in your storyboard. Another thing to consider is that you may have a view that just happens to be black (possibly no content in it), and fills the screen on top of everything.

Comment: Put some `NSLog` statements in key parts of your code, such as all of the app delegate methods and in the `viewDidLoad` of your main view controller. See what functions are actually getting called and where your program is performing its last execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have a navigation controller with no children. A navigation controller can be displayed with no children view controllers, but you'll get a black screen with a nav bar like you describe.

What does your storyboard look like?

Comment: I didn't set the root child controller, thanks Chris.

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding Story board entry point at the main story board
[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXlpB.png)

Thanks, Rajat